# Horizontal scrollbar always visible

Tags: html, scroll, scrollbar

I have a very high div on my website that also needs to be scrolled horizontally.

```
.scrollcontainer{
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:left; 
    width:fit-content; 
    max-width:90%; 
    min-width:70%; 
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align:top;
    height:75vh;
}
```

Is there a way to make horizontall scrollbar in a fixed position at the bottom of the website so no matter where the user is height-wise, they can also use horizontal scroll?

Tried styling the scrollbar by using webkit tools, but when i set it to `position:fixed` it made the scrollbar invisible (still working, just invisible).

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the [`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) property. According to MDN, the property "sets what shows when content overflows a block-level element's left and right edges", which depending on the setting could cause scrollbars to appear.

I think you want to set that property to `hidden` or `clip`.